# Access kubectl explain

Tags: go, kubectl

`kubectl explain` tells explains attribute of an object in kubectl. E.g. `k explain pod.spec.volumes.secret` gives you some insight about how to mount secrets into your pod.

I would like to write a wrapper for this in Go. **How do I access explain**? Afaik the [go client lib](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) cannot access this, because explain is a feature of `kubectl` and not the cluster itself. I would like to avoid writing a bash script, executing this from go and parsing the output.

Comment: What is gaoling?

Comment: Typo. Golang aka. Go. Let me correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `os/exec` package.

Using that package you can execute your kubectl command and parse the output.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("kubectl", "arg1", "arg2")
   
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(string(out.Bytes()))
}
```

Please find the documentation of that package [here](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec)

Alternatively, you could try to import the important bits of the `kubectl` package and call these functions from within your code. This could work, as `kubectl` is written in Go.

Have a look at that repo: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl

I have never tried that, so i can't give further hints.